# Duplicate column name 'id' CODEIGNITER

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

Hi i can't understand why i have this error

**This is a query:**

```
function get_num_post($args = array()) {
    $this->db->from("diario");
    if (isset($args["tag"]) && $args["tag"]) :
        $this->db->join("diario_tag_rif","diario_tag_rif.post_id = diario.id");
        $this->db->group_by("diario.id");
        $this->db->where("diario_tag_rif.tag_id",$args["tag"]->id);
    endif;
    if (isset($args["anno"]) && $args["anno"]) :
        $this->db->where("YEAR(diario.data)",$args["anno"]);
    endif;
    if (isset($args["mese"]) && $args["mese"]) :
        $this->db->where("MONTH(diario.data)",$args["mese"]);
    endif;
    $this->db->join("diario_categorie","diario_categorie.id = diario.categoria_id");
    return $this->db->count_all_results();
}
```

Please can you help me for my problem? Thank you so much :)

Comment: Removing irrelevant tag

Comment: where ? in join ?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to solve that, you may add the select function of query builder.

> $this->db->select("diario.*,diario.id as id_diario"); //mention here field will
>   you select and you should make an aliases of the id field.

So, the full script shown like this:

```
    function get_num_post($args = array()) {
        $this->db->from("diario");
$this->db->select("diario.*,diario.id as id_diario");
        if (isset($args["tag"]) && $args["tag"]) :
            $this->db->join("diario_tag_rif","diario_tag_rif.post_id = diario.id");
            $this->db->group_by("diario.id");
            $this->db->where("diario_tag_rif.tag_id",$args["tag"]->id);
        endif;
        if (isset($args["anno"]) && $args["anno"]) :
            $this->db->where("YEAR(diario.data)",$args["anno"]);
        endif;
        if (isset($args["mese"]) && $args["mese"]) :
            $this->db->where("MONTH(diario.data)",$args["mese"]);
        endif;
        $this->db->join("diario_categorie","diario_categorie.id = diario.categoria_id");
        return $this->db->count_all_results(); }
```

Goodluck!

Answer (score 0):

This means your both joining table has columns with same name `id`. All you have to do is use alias for those columns and separate name like

```
function get_num_post($args = array()) {
//put all columns required 
$this->db->select('diario.id dId,diario_tag_rif.id diId,diario_categorie.id dicId');
$this->db->from("diario");
//.....
```

Answer (score 0):

You should join first before use where and you can use group by after where clause.